# join query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

I am using join query in CodeIgniter and can't get it to work. It only displays one table data, but not the other. I am new to CodeIgniter and can't figure this out. Pleas someone help me. Tnanks in advance.

**view**

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

    <?php echo $row->answerA;?><br>
    <?php echo $row->answerB;?><br>
    <?php echo $row->answerC;?><br>
    <?php echo $row->comment;?><br>
    <?php echo $row->name; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**controller**

```
function getall() {

    $this->load->model('result_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
    // print_r($data['query']);
    // die();
    $this->load->view('result_view', $data);

}
```

**model**

```
function result_getall() {

    $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
    $this->db->from('tblanswers');
    $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'right outer'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

**EDIT**

The result of

```
print_r($data['query']);
die();
```

is an array as below:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => [userid] => [questionid] => [answerA] => [answerB] => [answerC] => [comment] => [cid] => 83 [name] => Edvinas [second_name] => liutvaits [phone] => [email] => ledvinas@yahoo.ie ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => [userid] => [questionid] => [answerA] => [answerB] => [answerC] => [comment] => [cid] => 84 [name] => Edvinas [second_name] => liutvaits [phone] => [email] => ledvinas@yahoo.ie ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => [userid] => [questionid] => [answerA] => [answerB] => [answerC] => [comment] => [cid] => 85 [name] => Edvinas [second_name] => Liutvaitis [phone] => [email] => ledvinas@yahoo.ie ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => [userid] => [questionid] => [answerA] => [answerB] => [answerC] => [comment] => [cid] => 86 [name] => EdvinasQ [second_name] => LiutvaitisQ [phone] => 12345678 [email] => ledvinas@yahoo.ie ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => [userid] => [questionid] => [answerA] => [answerB] => [answerC] => [comment] => [cid] => 87 [name] => Edvinas [second_name] => Liutvaitis [phone] => 123456 [email] => ledvinas@yahoo.ie ) )
```

**table structure**

credentials

cid(PRIMARY), name, second_name, phone, email

tblanswers

answerid(PRIMARY), userid, questionid, answerA, answerB, answerC.

Comment: visit page roytuts.com/codeigniter-join-example/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid');
```

Or

```
$this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'inner');
```

And print the result to see if is what you want

Comment: they both return an empty array any other suggestions ? tnx for your help.

Answer (score 5):

What's the primary table you want to query? Well you can try this one, suggested that when using joins, you must specify an alias for each table:

```
 function result_getall(){

    // if you want to query your primary data from the table 'tblanswers',
    $this->db->select('a.*,b.*'); <-- select what you might want to select
    $this->db->from('tblanswers a');
    $this->db->join('credentials b', 'b.cid = a.answerid', 'left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

    // if you want to query your primary data from the table 'credentials',

    $this->db->select('a.*,b.*'); <-- select what you might want to select
    $this->db->from('credentials a');
    $this->db->join('tblanswers b', 'b.answerid = a.cid', 'left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove select() tag, as u need all terms.

U can modify code like

```
$this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'outer'); 
$query = $this->db->get('tblanswers');
return $query->result();
```

Comment: i tried yuor code and all i got is an error here is the error 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `credentials` ON `tblanswers`.`answerid` = `credentials`.`cid`' at line 2

SELECT * LEFT JOIN `credentials` ON `tblanswers`.`answerid` = `credentials`.`cid`

Filename: C:\wamp\www\Surva\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: have u removed 'from' tag ? It also need to be removed

Answer (score 0):

If both of your tables are having the related, then it should work. Why are you using right outer join ? 
Simply use the Inner Join or any other join and it will work. Kindly read about different types of JOIN here  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp  and here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Hope this will help.

Thank you

Comment: inner join returns an empty array i left that i was only playing around with the join options to see which one will work for me. i tryed all the options well i thing i du the ones that were int the ci user guide and none of them return the two tables at the same time its ether one or the other.

Comment: Can you please add screen shots of the db tables so i can see the data? If all of the joins returns no data, then obviously the problem will be in data arrangement, or in the query. The query seems fine, but still cant say any thing. Please share the screen shots of both tables, so i can see the data of the both tables.

Comment: i edited the question and put up the table structure.

Comment: ok, please note that cid(primery) and answerid(primery) both should have same data (ids). try to run a sql query in phpmyadmin or any other tool you are using for mysql database, and check if you are getting any results or not? If you got results, then use that exact query using active records or a direct sql query in CI.