# formatting an array in specific way to show in a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two tables for Questions and Answers. The `answer` table has the primary key of the `question` table as a foreign key.
I have retrived the data using a join query as follows.

```
public function getData() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $this->db->join('answer', 'answer.question_id = question.question_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I want to format the array in the following way. And echo the result in the view.

```
$question_array[question_number] = array(
    'question_text' =>$question,
    'answers'=>array(
        'answer1' =>$answer1,
        'answer2'=>$answer2,
    ),
);
```

**EDIT :**

`getData()` function returns the following

```
  array(1){
 [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (6) {
 ["question_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["question"]=> string(15) "What is my name" 
 ["type"]=> string(3) "mcq" 
 ["answer_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["answer"]=> string(6) "Lahiru" ["correct"]=> string(1) "C" } }
```

Comment: so what's a common result if you return `$query->result_array()`??

Comment: You should loop your query result and change it in the required array..

Comment: @AG21 that's what i'm trying to do. Can you please show me an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218315/join-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: @CraZyDroiD what array is returned from `getData()` in current scenario? Will you please add that in your question?

Comment: @AG21 i have included in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
   public function getData() {
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('question');
       $this->db->join('answer', 'answer.question_id = question.question_id');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       $query_result = $query->result();
       $question_array = array(); 

       foreach ($query_result as $row) { 
           $temp = array();
           $temp['question_text'] = $row->question;

           //Change below line as its not clear from the returned array you mentioned
           $temp['answers'] = $row->answer;

           $question_array[$row->question_id] = $temp;
       }
       return $question_array;
   }
```