# Join multiple tables in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can join 2  tables with another by same fields in php codeigniter
Eg. 
I have 3 table
      student with adm_number
      Staff with pe_numbber
      And bookhistory with usernumber 
 How can join student and staff table to bookhistory 
  simultaneously by comparing with usernumber

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218315/join-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: all three tables having `usernumber` column?

Comment: No table bookhistory have usernumber then using this field I have to compare adm_number of student table and pe_numbber of staff table

Comment: Like$this->db->select('*'); $this->db->from bookhistory ; $this->db->join(student.,'student. Adm_number =bookhistory. Usernumber') ; $this->db->join(staff.,'staff. Pe_number =bookhistory. Usernumber') ;

Comment: please add this in your question.

Comment: did you tried this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem. If possible add the relevant code and error. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your target as:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('student');
$this->db->join('staff', 'student.adm_number = staff.pe_numbber');
$this->db->join('bookhistory', 'student.adm_number = bookhistory.usernumber');
```